# Umbraco URL without domain prefix for the multisite setup

Tags: url, hyperlink, umbraco, multilingual

We have mutli site setup with "UseDomainPrefixes" set to true and have applied the hostname on the root level of each site but what is required is "Link to Document" to should be the url with-out the domain/hostname prefix. I was able to achieve this in umbraco4.0.2 but we recently upgrade to 4.8.0 and this upgrade has replaced all the links with domain prefix. Is there any way to achieve tihs in 4.8.0.

Site setup and url of a page in umbraco 4.0.2
[image]

Hence the link to document doesn't have the domain prefix set on it only for the first site even though "UseDomainPrefixes" set to true. i need to replicate exactly the same thing in 4.8.0 due to the way the site has been setup.

The same page in umbraco4.8.0
[image]

Please Help, Much Appreciated.

Thanks

Aneesh

Comment: You could actually argue that this was a bug/failing in v4.0. If you have hosts defined *and* UseDomainPrefixes set to true, I would expect the behaviour you are seeing in 4.8.0. If you set UseDomainPrefixes to false, your setup should still work but I think you should get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks @Digbyswift for your reply, but can the feature/bug in v4.0 be replicated in v4.8.0, I need that badly because the site was build in v4.0 and all the logic in place works on based on these URL. So if I can't replicate v4.0 then it will be a hard time to change all the rules in place which is a tedious process.